# How can I create two columns of text next to each other using CSS?

Tags: css

I'm trying to determine the best way to format two columns of text like this using CSS:

(take the ----- as spaces)

dfasfasdfsa ------------  fdafsadfasdfasdf

fdsafadsfaf ------------  fadsdsafasfsaf

fdfgfgdsdffd -----------  fgdhfjshkjahjkh

fdljkgjklkj ---------------  jfkldjskafljaf

I could brute force position it, but I'm sure there must be an easier way..any advice? Sorry for the beginner question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use two division tags and set their `float` property

```
<div style='float:left; width:30%'>
    Put your content here...
</div>

<div style='float:left; width:40%; margin-left:30px'>
    Put another content here...
</div>
```

With the `float` property, the two `divs` will be aligned sideways, the `margin-left` property will give a margin between the two division.

You could optionally put the CSS in a separate file, then use `id` or `class` to reference it.

Answer (score 4):

css3 columns work on modern browsers, no support for  IE8 or under.

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multicolumn.html
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS3_Columns

You can define the number of columns and the space between columns:

```
div {column-count:2; column-gap: 20px;}
```

Alternatively, the jQuery columnizer plugin works cross browser:

http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/

Comment: This is OK (with the usual CSS Caveats about browser support) if the question is interpreted as requesting for a run of text to be shown in two columns so that it continues from bottom of 1st column to top of 2nd column (as opposite to two different pieces of text).

Comment: yea... kind of difficult to interpret one way or the other with "adlkajsdasdad" :)

Answer (score 1):

I have extended Chibuzo's solution and here it is:

CSS:

```
.col1 {
    float:left; 
    width:100px;
    background-color: #E8F6F7;
}

.col2 {
    float:left; 
    width:200px; 
    margin-left:30px;
    background-color: #f2dede;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col1">                          
    <div>Monday:</div>
    <div>Tuesday:</div> 
    <div>Wednesday:</div>                           
</div>

<div class="col2">
    <div>open 8am to 5pm</div>
    <div>open 9am to 4pm</div>   
    <div>open 9am to 6pm</div>                           
</div>
```

and it looks like this:

[image]

I had been trying to do it with CSS *position*, *relative* and *absolute*, which is possible but can be rather frustrating.